# How to implement a dynamic reducer creator for API service call in React with Redux project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Since I may have many API services to call, I have to write as many as reducers for these services, is there any way to implement an reducer creators dynamically like below?

```
const PENDING = 'PENDING'
const REJECTED = 'REJECTED'
const FULFILLED = 'FULFILLED'
const COMPANIES = 'COMPANIES'

let createReducer = (name) => (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case name + '_' + PENDING:
      return {...state, 
        isLoading: false
      }
    case name + '_' + FULFILLED:
      return {...state, 
        companies: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      }
    case name + '_' + REJECTED:
      return {...state, 
        isLoading: false,
        err: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

let comapnyReducer = createReducer(COMPANIES)
```

Which can be equivalent to below explicit implementation:

```
const comapnyReducer = (state={isLoading: false}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case 'COMPANIES_PENDING':
    return {...state, 
      isLoading: false
    }
  case 'COMPANIES_FULFILLED':
    return {...state, 
      companies: action.payload,
      isLoading: false
    }
  case 'COMPANIES_REJECTED':
    return {...state, 
      isLoading: false,
      err: action.payload
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Comment: how should state looks like, on output

Answer (score 1):

goal of this example is to illustrate how it might be. your implementation may be different in details.

[DEMO JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qufila/4/edit?js,console)

```
const PENDING = 'PENDING'
const REJECTED = 'REJECTED'
const FULFILLED = 'FULFILLED'

const reducer = (state={isLoading:false}, action) => {
  const {name, type} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case name + '_' + PENDING:
      return {...state, isLoading: false }
    case name + '_' + FULFILLED:
      return {...state,
        items: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      }
    case name + '_' + REJECTED:
      return {...state,
        isLoading: false,
        err: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const entities = (state={},action)=>{
  if(action.name){
    const name = action.name.toLowerCase()
    return {...state, [name]:reducer(state[name],action)  }
  }else{
     return state
  }
}
```

**action example**

```
{type:'COMPANIES_FULFILLED',name:'COMPANIES',payload:[1,2,3,4]}
```

**result**

```
    "companies": {
        "items": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "isLoading": false
    },
    "messages": {
        "items": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "isLoading": false
    }
```

Comment: As I see, you actually put one more attribute 'name' into action, to let the reducer to calculate the const value of action type. In my case, I applied the redux-promise-middleware, so that the payload in the action object is a promise and the action type would be dynamically changed with different API calling phase. But I am not sure why the reducer cannot aware of the 'name' attribute of action object.

Comment: And one more important thing is, even if I can successfully dispatch the action to reducers, things may go wrong since if any part of your components meet the error, the reducer would not correctly generated which means the whole state machine would stuck somewhere.  So I began to rethink whether this kind of approach to generate the dynamic reducer is kind of anti-pattern or not? or there is much better way?

Comment: The dispatcher above, ```dispatch({ type: "COMPANIES", payload: fetch(http://mydomain/companies/, {credentials: 'include'}).then(response => response.json()), name: "COMPANIES" }) ```